# SwiftUI: padding above my view, for no reason?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to create an Instagram-like UI with SwiftUI, and since I wasn't able to resize the tab elements in the `TabView`, I decided to write a simple `CustomTabView` instead. But I end up with a padding at the top of it and I don't understand why. Here is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedIndex: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch selectedIndex {
            case 0:
                Color.blue
            case 1:
                Color.yellow
            case 2:
                Color.red
            case 3:
                Color.orange
            default:
                Color.green
            }
            CustomTabView(selectedIndex: $selectedIndex)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTabView: View {
    @Binding var selectedIndex: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider()
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    selectedIndex = 0
                }, label: {
                    Image("HomeIcon")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                })
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    selectedIndex = 1
                }, label: {
                    Image("PlayIcon")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                })
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    selectedIndex = 2
                }, label: {
                    Image("AddIcon")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                })
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    selectedIndex = 3
                }, label: {
                    Image("HeartIcon")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                })
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    selectedIndex = 4
                }, label: {
                    Image("ProfileIcon")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                })
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 24)
            .padding(.top, 4)
        }
        .background(Color.white)
    }
}
```

The result I'm getting:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem is the gap between the blue box and the divider, try setting the spacing of the `VStack` to 0:

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Top Space

That is the [safe area](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/#layout-guides-and-safe-area). You can ignore it with this modifier:

```
.ignoresSafeArea()
```

Apply it to the view you want it to extend beyond the safe area, for example:

```
Color.blue
    .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)
```

## Bottom Space

That is the spacing of the `VStack`. Get rid of it by setting that to 0:

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    ,,,
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I tried it but the gap still appears

Comment: Maybe you are doing it wrong, I'm seeing it with no issues. Can you upload a piece of code on git?

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't explain the issue correctly. I am not talking about the screen's top safe area, but the gap between the bottom of the blue view and the top of the tab view. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Image("background").resizable()
                   .scaledToFill()
                   .clipped()
                   .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top])
```